# Select and delete specific rows in Excel from text file

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to select a *lot* of rows in Excel in order to delete them, and doing this manually literaly takes hours. I have the specific row numbers in a .txt file with a number on each line. Like this:

```
1
5
8
9
```

Is there some cool way to tell Excel to select/delete these lines automatically?

Example:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/ccQegoC.png]

Comment: What is the condition that must be met to delete a row?

Comment: There isn't any logical condition. The row is deleted due to a specific vendor not working with us anymore - seemingly random rows. So I have the specific rows (1, 5, 8, 9 as in the example) in a text file and need to select/delete these rows.

Comment: Selecting the rows, right clicking, and selecting delete is the fastest way to delete rows in excel. You could supposedly use VBA but there would be no speed increase.

Comment: If you want to delete multiple rows for the same vendor then that's a different story and you can use VBA to do so, to find all occurrences.

Comment: Let's say I have a document with 2000 rows of data and I need to delete 500 of them in random locations - it can easily take 20-30 minutes if not more. If I could somehow run a e.g. VBA script on the seperate text file selecting the specific lines, we're talking about seconds of work. Do you know if Kutools can be in use?

Comment: So the initial situation is that you have a bunch of text files in one directory that contain the data? Can you give an example of how these text files are formatted? I don't know what Kutools is but VBA should be able to handle external text files no problem without having to import all the data to Excel first.

Comment: I don't know if this website allows new lines, but the file is just numbers on new lines:
1
5
8
12

Okay, so obviously not working, but I think you catch my drift.

Comment: Even a simple solution like having a text field in Excel where I could go "hey Eric (Excel), please delete/select line 1, 5, 8, 12, 152 for me, would ya?" would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get you started on the VBA side of things.  I created a workbook that has two fields, Vendor and the File location. I also created a VBA sub procedure that will open the text file and replace any line that = the vendor number with a return carriage on the end of it and replace that with nothing (""):

```
Sub Remove_line_item()
Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer
myFile = Range("B2").Value
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, textline
text = text & textline
Loop
text = Replace(text, Range("A2").Value & ChrW(14), "")

myFile.Write text
myFile.Close
End Sub
```

[image]

I only used one file path at a time but you could go one step further and go through all text files in a directory too. This could be a good start for you though hopefully.